# Why the difference in these results of estimating the parameters of Erlang distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Investigating (in 13.2 on Windows 10) the  `FindDistributionParameters` command for learning purpose, I consider
a small sample   `{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}` from a possible statistical population distributed as
[ErlangDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ErlangDistribution.html?q=ErlangDistribution).
I estimate the parameters, making use of different methods.

```
FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 
ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

> `{k -> 6, \[Lambda] -> 2.47934}`

The above is identical to the result of

```
NMaximize[{LogLikelihood[ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], {1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}],
k \[Element] PositiveIntegers && \[Lambda] >= 0}, {k, \[Lambda]}, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}]
```

and

```
FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9},  ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "FindMaximum"}]
```

clearly says that `k` must be a positive integer number.

Then

```
FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9},  ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 
ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]
```

> `{k -> 4.91309, \[Lambda] -> 2.0302}`

and

```
FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9},  ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 
ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfCentralMoments"]
```

produces the same. The value of `k` is not integer, but the documentation says
"Method-of-moment-based estimators may not satisfy all restrictions on parameters".

Let us write down

```
eq1 = Moment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 1] == Moment[ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 1]
eq2 = Moment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 2] == Moment[ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 2]
```

,equating sample moments and distribution moments, and solve the system

```
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {k, \[Lambda]}, Reals]
```

> `{{k -> 6.14136, \[Lambda] -> 2.53775}}`

We see the difference in the values: `{k -> 4.91309, \[Lambda] -> 2.0302}` vs `{k -> 6.14136, \[Lambda] -> 2.53775}`.
How to explain it?

PS.  [CASE:5013654]

Comment: `FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 
 ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MethodOfMoments", "MomentOrders" -> {1, 3}}]` performs `{k -> 6.56024, \[Lambda] -> 2.71084}`.

Comment: `Solve[CentralMoment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 1] == 
   CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 1] && 
  CentralMoment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 2] == 
   CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
    2], {\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, Reals]` produces `{{\[Sigma]->-0.976524},{\[Sigma]->0.976524}}` and  `Solve[CentralMoment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 3] == 
   CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 3] && 
  CentralMoment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 2] == 
   CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
    2], {\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, Reals]` produces `{}`.

Comment: In the above we see that defect occurs for other distributions too.

Comment: The problem is that you don't understand that the first central moment for all sample data and distributions with a mean is zero and therefore does not contain any information for estimating the parameters.  Now it certainly doesn't help that for two-parameter distributions *Mathematica* uses the first raw moment (the mean) and the second central moment when one chooses "MethodOfCentralMoments" if one doesn't specify the moment orders to use.

Comment: Even much worse the result of `Solve[Moment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 1] == 
   Moment[TriangularDistribution[{min, max}, c], 1] && 
  Moment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 2] == 
   Moment[TriangularDistribution[{min, max}, c], 2], {min, max, 
  c}, Reals]` , though `FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 
 TriangularDistribution[{min, max}, c], 
 ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]` produces `{min -> 0.246228, max -> 4.98257, c -> 2.0312}`.

Comment: It's much worse using `Solve` because you have 3 parameters and only 2 equations.  If you use 3 moments and restrict the solutions to min < c < max, then you'll get exactly what the "MethodOfMoments" gets you.

Comment: @JimB: You are right here. Concerning central moments for normal distribution,  `FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 
 NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MethodOfCentralMoments", 
   "MomentOrders" -> {2, 4}}]`  returns `{\[Mu]->2.5,\[Sigma]->1.09243}`, but

Comment: `Reduce[CentralMoment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 2] == 
   CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 2] && 
  CentralMoment[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 4] == 
   CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
    4], {\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, Reals]` returns `False`.

Comment: Moreover, `FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 
 NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MethodOfCentralMoments", 
   "MomentOrders" -> {1, 2}}]` results in `{\[Mu] -> 2.42, \[Sigma] -> 0.976524}`, though in fact we have only one equation.

Comment: Actually there are no *Mathematica* equations rather than 1 in the above comment.  The  equivalent approach using `Solve` is `data = {1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9};
Solve[{Mean[data] == Mean[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]], 
StandardDeviation[data] Sqrt[(Length[data] - 1)/Length[data]] ==
 StandardDeviation[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]]}, {\[Mu], \[Sigma]}]`.

Comment: For your `Reduce` command you failed to mention the warning "Encountered a singular Jacobian...." when means the "2.5" for the mean is just the starting value.  The real issue is that the second and fourth central moments only depend on $\sigma$ and not at all on $\mu$ so $\mu$ can't be estimated with those two sample statistics.

Answer (score 3):

I can explain what causes the difference but not why.

Your use of the raw moments can be rewritten in the following manner:

```
data = {1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9};
Solve[{Mean[data] == Mean[ErlangDistribution[k, λ]], 
  data.data/Length[data] == Moment[ErlangDistribution[k, λ], 2]}]
(* {{k -> 6.14136, \[Lambda] -> 2.53775}} *)
```

But what `FindDistributionParameters` does is essentially one or both of the following:

```
Solve[{Mean[data] == Mean[ErlangDistribution[k, λ]], 
  Variance[data] == Variance[ErlangDistribution[k, λ]]}, {k, λ}]
(* {{k -> 4.91309, λ -> 2.0302}} *)

Solve[{Mean[data] == Mean[ErlangDistribution[k, λ]], 
  Variance[data] + Mean[data]^2 == Moment[ErlangDistribution[k, λ], 2]}]
(* {{k -> 4.91309, λ -> 2.0302}} *)
```

The differences in the approaches will get smaller with larger sample sizes.

Comment: Thank for your explanation. It seems that `FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9},  ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 
ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfCentralMoments"]` returning the same `{k -> 4.91309, λ -> 2.0302}` also does not use any method of central moments.

Comment: Also `FindDistributionParameters[{1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9}, 
 ErlangDistribution[k, \[Lambda]], 
 ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfCumulants"]` returns the same `{k -> 4.91309, \[Lambda] -> 2.0302}`.

Comment: Therefore,  the documentation to `FindDistributionParameters` does not correspond to reality. I find it dangerous.

Comment: The documentation gives the standard warning that you posted "Method-of-moment-based estimators may not satisfy all restrictions on parameters".  The use of moments also doesn't always use all of the available information to estimate parameters.  The warnings are there.

Comment: If one just uses the first two cumulants, those correspond exactly to the mean and variance, respectively.  It would be only if more or other cumulants are selected, would "MethodOfCumulants" provide a different set of estimates.

Comment: Sorry, " The use of moments also doesn't always use all of the available information to estimate parameters. The warnings are there" is your personal opinion.  I don't find it in the documentation. Also `Variance` is the second central moment, not a moment.

Comment: From the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics): "Also, estimates by the method of moments are not necessarily sufficient statistics, i.e., they sometimes fail to take into account all relevant information in the sample."

Comment: Are you serious? [Sufficient statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) is off topic here. I repeat "Also `Variance` is the second central moment, not a moment".

Answer (score 1):

If `k` is constrained to be a positive integer, "MethodOfMoments" is equivalent to "MaximumLikelihood"

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 3.1, 3.9};

dist = ErlangDistribution[k, λ];

param1 = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]

(* {k -> 6, λ -> 2.47934} *)

DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* k ∈ Integers && k > 0 && λ > 0 *)
```

**Constrain `k` to be a positive integer**

```
Off[Solve::ratnz]

kVal = Round[SolveValues[
    Moment[dist, #] == Moment[data, #] & /@ {1, 2},
    k, {λ}][[1]]]

(* 6 *)

param2 = Prepend[
  FindDistributionParameters[data,
   ErlangDistribution[kVal, λ],
   ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"],
  k -> kVal]

(* {k -> 6, λ -> 2.47934} *)

param3 = Prepend[Solve[
    {Moment[ErlangDistribution[kVal, λ], 1] ==
      Moment[data, 1], λ > 0}, λ][[1]], k -> kVal]

(* {k -> 6, λ -> 2.47934} *)

param1 == param2 == param3

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. Unfortunately, that you use is not any method of moments. In particular, it is known that rounding may not produce an optimal solution.  Therefore, your claim "If `k` is constrained to be a positive integer, "MethodOfMoments" is equivalent to "MaximumLikelihood"" does not correspond to reality.

Comment: If `k` is not an integer then the distribution is not a valid `ErlangDistribution` and does not "correspond to reality". To enforce an integer parameter, an integer function is required (e.g., `Round`, `Ceiling`, or `Floor`) with the method of moments used to determine `k`. And both `param2` and `param3` continued to use a method of moments to find the remaining parameter.

Comment: As @JimB demonstrates in his answer,  in fact,  `ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"`  likely does not use any method of moments, but you apply this option. This is a point.

Comment: Just a note that the Erlang distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution with the restriction that $k$ is an integer.  When $k$ is not an integer, plugging that into the Erlang pdf formula results in a legitimate gamma pdf.